# How to force Update from a Laravel Eloquent ModelObserver instead of allowing it to create new record

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I am trying to customize the Laravel Spatie Tags package within my Laravel Nova deployment to use it within a multi-tenant environment. To be able to do so, I am appending the tenant ID in the tag type property so that I can keep tag types separate for each tenant. Below is the saving event within the model observer.

```
public function saving(Tag $tag)
    {
        $user_id = auth()->guard()->user()->id;
        $user = \App\Models\Auth\User::with('tenant')->find($user_id);
        $tenant_id = $user->tenant->id;
        $tag->type =  $tag_type . '_tenant_id_' . $tenant_id;
    }
```

I remove the tenant id information during the read time by using the retreived event within the observer as below so that this meta-data type information is not displayed to the user.

```
public function retrieved(Tag $tag)
    {
        $tag->type = preg_replace(['/_tenant_id_\d*/'], [''], $tag->type);
    }
```

However, the above causes duplicate tags to be created because the underlying findOrCreate method within the Spatie tags package gets called prior to the Observer events so it doesnt see the modified tag type value when determining whether the tag already exist. Is there a way I can force update instead of create from within the observer saving event?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using an attribute mutator instead of your current solution:

In your Tag model:

```php
public function getTypeAttribute($value) {
    return  preg_replace(['/_tenant_id_\d*/'], [''], $value);
}
public function setTypeAttribute($value) {
    $user_id = auth()->guard()->user()->id;
    $user = \App\Models\Auth\User::with('tenant')->find($user_id);
    $tenant_id = $user->tenant->id;
    $this->attributes['type'] = $value . '_tenant_id_' . $tenant_id;
}
```

This way you can ensure the correct round trip of this value. However if you do ever do something like `$tag->type = 'X_tenant_id_1';` you'd get something like `X_tenant_id_1_tenant_id_1` saved so you might need to check for that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know how it goes. This definitely seems better than the Observer approach.

Comment: @user2318002 just as a sidenote, `type` here is denormalized so another solution would be to have `tenant_id` as a foreign key and imposing a unique constraint on the pair `type, tenant_id`